# Unable to Read File in Android

Tags: android, file

This is probably a stupid question, but I am creating a function that is getting data from a file to checkout. I am trying to use a buffered reader and file reader in this function, although bufferredReader.readLine() is always returning null. There is also no logcat. I need some help. There are two methods, one that saves to the file, and another that retrieves data from the file. I already know that the data is getting passed into the saving to file function correctly.

Here is the saving to file function:

```
 public boolean saveToBill(Editable user, Editable points, Editable mows) {
        String FILENAME = "/billDrafts";
        String string = user + "," + points + "," + mows;
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.getFilesDir() + FILENAME);
            writer.write(string);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to checkout. Click the 3 dots, then checkout to complete billing process." + string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to save file for checkout.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the function for reading from the file:

```
    public void checkout() {
        String FILENAME = this.getFilesDir() + "/billDrafts";
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String bills = bufferedReader.readLine();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Checkout Complete" + bills, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            bufferedReader.close();
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Checkout Failed. Make sure you have somebody to bill.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Checkout Failed. An unknown error occurred during checkout.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems your writer is not flushed, after done with writing, you need to call `writer.flush()` in order to flush the buffer into the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `saveToBill` is not really writing the data into the file. You either need to call `flush()` or `close()` on the writer in order to pass the buffered data into the actual file.

As you are doing neither of them, your file is empty, hence your `readLine()` is returning null.

There is a slight difference between `flush()` and `close()`, you can read up on them

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That was the solution. StackOverflow isn't letting me accept for 2 minutes, but I promise I will. Thank you.